# How does one add one's own bespoke inputComponent JSX <input /> to a react-phone-number-input PhoneInput?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

Code follows this description.

`react-phone-number-input` allows uses to replace its default `<input />` JSX tag with one's own, which specifically requires the type `React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & React.RefAttributes<any>>` and needs a `forwardRef` (to allow access to the `<input />`).

Whilst I believe I have provided this with `myTextInput` the compiler is complaining that:

`Property '$$typeof' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<...` and
`Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<...`

OK, `myTextInput = <ForwardedInput` does return an `<input />` JSX so yes it is a React `Element` and therefore the error messages make some sense. But said tag will resolve to a `React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & React.RefAttributes<any>>` so how can I get the compiler to recognise that?

Thank you for reading.

```
import React, { forwardRef, InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'

const ForwardedInput = forwardRef<any, InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>(
    (props, ref) => {
        const { onChange, value } = props;
        return (
            <input
                type="text"
                ref={ref}
                onChange={onChange}
                value={value}
            />
        );
    }
);

const MyPhoneInput = () => {

    const ref = React.createRef();
    const myTextInput = <ForwardedInput 
        onChange={() => {}}
        value="string"
        ref={ref}
    />;

    return (
        <div>
            <PhoneInput
                    placeholder="Enter phone number"
                    value={"value"}
                    inputComponent={myTextInput}
                    onChange={() => {
                        return;
                    }}
                />
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyPhoneInput;
```

Answer (score -1):

For those who are suffering the same problem, a quick fix is to go to this lib (smaller and you can pass input props):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-2

Answer (score -3):

`inputComponent={ForwardedInput}`

this works. for now my life is so incredibly busy i don't have time for a detailed explanation but will come back to this asap.

Comment: I appreciate that you are OP, and this answer might make sense to you, but it might be helpful to explain how you arrived at this answer.

Comment: Please add at least basic explanation about this 1 lane, it will help future readers to better understand why you had this problem and why this lane solved this.

Comment: you're both right, will endeavour to do so asap